# Split up an array into specific size pieces and turn them into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var awn = [];
//sets up an empty array
  if(size < 0) {
    return arr;
  } else if(size === 1) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i += size) {
      awn.push(arr[i]);
    }
  } else if(size === 2) {
    for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x += size) {
      awn.push([arr[x], arr[x + 1]]);
    }
  } else if(size === 3) {
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j += size) {
      awn.push([arr[j], arr[j + 1], arr[j + 2]]);
    }
  } else if(size === 4) {
    awn.push([arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]],[arr[4], arr[5]]);

  }
  return awn;
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4);
```

This is what I wrote to try and tackle this issue, but I assume that it could be done a bit more elagantly, plus the fact that it only works if the size is less than 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reducer, and using the remainder operator you can check when to split:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, x, i) {
    if (i % size === 0) {
      acc.push([x])
    } else {
      acc[acc.length-1].push(x)
    }
    return acc
  },[])
}

chunk([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 4)
//^ [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9]]
```